# How to get variables from a python script

Tags: google-colaboratory

I'm running [this code](https://github.com/google-research/albert/blob/master/albert_glue_fine_tuning_tutorial.ipynb) for ALBERT, one of Google's machine learning models on Google Colab. At the end of the code, they do everything by running a script using `!` (the shell) to run the script. However, I'd like to do some stuff to the resulting model after the code has run.

**Is there any way to either access or get the script to output particular variables in a way that my code in Colab could access afterwards?**

Here's another way of phrasing my question. Putting `$HELLO_WORLD` into the shell command *accesses* the `HELLO_WORLD` variable in my Colab code. **Is there any way to get the script to *set* the `HELLO_WORLD` variable in my Colab code?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `os.environ` like this.

```
import os
os.environ['HELLO_WORLD']='hello world from Python'
```

Then later

```
!echo $HELLO_WORLD

# hello world from Python
```